# How do I read a variable output from an html form and use it in the webpage?

Tags: html, xml, forms

OK, I've tried to get this to work - but just can't seem to see the way...

What I am trying to do is have a form ask for an index, when I submit it will read an XML file (bowlist.xml) and give me the data for the matching index.

Here is the entire code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="">
Bowl #: <input type="text" name="bowlidx" value="" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit"  />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

var index = <%=Request.QueryString(bowlidx)%>

document.write('index is ' + index)

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","bowlist.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
    if(x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue != index) continue;
        document.write("<tr><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("code")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("image")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I get the form, enter and submit the index, and nothing happens.

Where am I going wrong on this?

I should add that the javascript search does work if I enter an existing index in the "if(x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue != index)" line.

Comment: Your code snippet is incomplete.Correct the given code or post it in a fiddle.

Comment: Which code is incorrect? The 2nd code snippet works, I just included it to give some idea of what I am trying to do. The form code is what I have from another source, that's wat I am asking about. And what is a 'fiddle'?

Comment: The 2nd one is incomplete, is it from a javascript function? Where this function is defined ? Fiddle is a site to post sample code snippets. Link : http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Yes, it's javascript. As I told Stardev, I'm too tired to continue this right now - sorry about that. Thanks for the help to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want this when the page loads (i.e. after you click the submit button and the page reloads), you could use a line of server-side code to set your variable in javascript, like so:

```
index = <%=Request.QueryString("bowlidx")%>
```

Comment: Think I misinterpreted your question. Updated my answer.

Comment: Do you mean in the action="" line?

Comment: OK, I'm lost - when you say "in javascript" is that before the form or after - or part of it. Assume I really don't understand much about js...

Comment: The line should be inside your javascript code, replacing `index = result //423`. Note that I assume that this javascript code is on `form_action.asp` (your form's `action`).

Comment: It may be - but I have not found form_action.asp...I'm assuming that's a file this writes to. And that's part of my confusion, since I am wondering if I need to write to form_action.asp and then read it, or can I just get the result directly without having to read a file? I apologize for being so dense, but it's just been too long since I did any of this, and even then did not get this deep into it.

Comment: No problem. Your form's `action` attribute tells you to what page your browser redirects after you click the submit button. At that page you should process the form input data. So if you want to do an XML search after the form is submitted and the page is refreshed, you should do it there.

Comment: OK, I just put your code in the jscript, loaded the html and submitted an index - I get a 404 error that the form_action.asp file can't be found. Is this where my problem is, it isn't being created? I assumed it was in the same directory the html is in.

Comment: You most likely entered the `form_action.asp` yourself. You can change the action into anything you want.

Comment: That's what I was hoping - how do I change that action to save the result on the same page so I can use it? (the asp file was in the example I copied, wasn't sure what that was doing...)

Comment: Simply change `action="form_action.asp"` to `action=""`

Comment: And the index = <%=Request.QueryString("bowlidx")%> goes after the form, in the javascript?

Comment: Yes it should replace `index = result //423`

Comment: OK, that still doesn't seem to do anything. It's late & I'm probably too tired to make sense of this. I'll play with this more tomorrow. You have pointed me it the right direction, and for that I thank you...I shouldn't start these projects when I am tired...thanks.

Comment: Did you submit the form? Check the page source to see if a number is written next to `index = ...`

Comment: It isn't. I'll look at it when I can make some sense, I just stated nodding off as I wrote this, <G>

Comment: In your updated code be sure to change `<%=Request.QueryString(bowlidx)%>` into `<%=Request.QueryString("bowlidx")%>` (with the quotes, as shown in my answer)

Comment: I made that change - I get the form, enter the index, and all that happens is the number clears, don't see the index posted to the page. I am running this on the local server under xampp, with both the code and xml in hdocs. Do I need to put this in a separate folder?